# my query does not work like in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

my url is 
http://localhost:3000/API/GetEvents?search=prueba

my response is 
[]

this is my code

```
var query = req.param("search");
        console.log(query);
        Event.find({name: /query/}).sort({ created_at: 'desc' }).populate('moderator').exec(function (err, events) {
        if (err) throw err;

        var response = [];
        events.forEach(function (ev) {

            var moderatorName = ev.moderator.facebook.name;

            if (ev.isFanPage)
                moderatorName = ev.fanPageName;

            response.push({ eventId: ev._id, title: ev.name, description: ev.description, thumb: ev.thumb, moderator: moderatorName, moderatorFbId: ev.moderator.facebook.id, countPicture: '1', countVideo: '1' });
        });

        next(response);
       });
```

my search parameter is req.param("search") and include in my query find the parameter.

as it should search for the field?

Comment: `Event.find({ "name": new RegExp(query) })` or `{ "name": { "$regex": query } }`. Otherwise it's actually looking for the "string" `"query"` and does not interpolate the variable.

Comment: thank your solution "{" name ": new RegEx (query)}" works

Comment: for {"name": new RegExp(query)}  as add the optional parameter "i"?

Comment: See [`RegExp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) and [`$regex`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/) documentation.

Comment: I think there is another issue: `if (err) throw err;`, it should be `return error`.